# Как на c# selenium firefox открыть новую вкладку?

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

Все что нашел - перепробовал, ничего не работает.
Есть актуальное решение?

Answer (score 1):

я давно как-то делал. Предаполагаю что сработает простое SendKeys на любой элемент страницы в который ты закинешь "Ctrl+T". Что-то вроде:

```
.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.T));
```

или

```
.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

Если не сработает - можно открыть вкладку через JS.

```
.executeScript("window.open()");
```

но вообще с табами через селениум не советую игратся ибо он отвратительно работает с вкладками - он для этого не предназначен.

Comment: тогда как альтернативное решение - открытие вкладки через JS.

Comment: В последней лисе - открытие вкладки через JS тоже не работает